# Remove a file from input type="file" multiple through jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I am having a problem in file upload form using PHP and jQuery. form can upload multiple images at a time which can be previewed in a slider with a form that consists of two more fields caption and description. slider is working through jQuery. when a user selects multiple images by clicking on choose file(`<input type="file" multiple=""/>`) all the images will be shown in slider with other two fields(caption and description). Each image has these two fields to add some description and caption. if a user wants to remove an image he don't want to upload he will click on remove button to remove that image (this remove button will be appended with each image) I have used .remove() function to remove an image  and its two fields from the slider but the problem arises when i submit the form at server side image is removing only from the slider not from the `input type="file"` and its getting submitted to the server. I know input type file is **"readonly"** but please help me is there anyway to do this so that I can stop that removed image from uploading at server. here is the code.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div> 
 <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple" id="my_file" onChange="readURL(this);"/>
</div>
 <div class="pic_preview">     
  <a class="prev" href="#">Previous</a> 

  <ul>

 </ul>

  <a class="next" href="#"><b>Next</b></a>

</div>
 <div class="set">
<ul>
</ul> 
 </div>
 <button class="btns">Cancel
</button>
<button class="post_btn">Post
</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(".my_file").change(function() {
      readURL(this);   
    });
    function readURL(input){
  for(var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) { 
      if (input.files && input.files[i]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){

          $('.pic_preview ul').append("<li id="counter'+ e.target.result +'"><imgid="counter'+ e.target.result +'" style="width:500px; height:350px; border:10px;border-radius:10px;" src="' + e.target.result + '"/><input type="button"class="rem" value="remove"/></li>");

         $('.set ul').append("<li id="counter'+ e.target.result +'"><inputtype="text"name="caps[]" id="text" class="set" placeholder="Caption"/><textareaname="description[]"class="description" placeholder="description"></textarea<p><inputname="Tags[]" type="text"  id="text" class="set" placeholder="Tags"/></p></li>");};

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);

};   

};
$('.pic_preview ul').bind('click', 'input', function(event){
     var removeItemID = $('input').parent("li").attr('id');
    // $("li img[id='"+removeItemID+"']").remove(); 
     $("li[id='"+removeItemID+"']").remove();
    $(".set li[id='"+removeItemID+"']").remove();
    });

      }
```

Please help me or suggest if there is any better approach than this.

Comment: Would I be completely wrong in suggesting that the way that this works is by cloning the input type=file + hiding the origonal each time you add a file? if thats the case then you'll need to find the hidden input.

Comment: input type file is not cloning. it has only one choose image option i am not making its clone.

Comment: tumblr and facebook are also using upload forms in which we can delete an image we don't want to upload. i am just having problem when i upload a file on server. please help me i want its solution as soon as possible :(

Comment: Can you try create a quick jsfiddle? OR show some HTML generated AFTER adding a few files to the form?

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/z7br8/3/ its just a prototype i am selecting and showing only one image at a time. but i can highlight my problem you can see image can be removed from DOM but not from input type file still its name is showing with Choose File button so when i will submit my form it will uploaded to the server.